# "in like manner" vs. "in a like manner"

Tags: phrases

Can "in a like manner" and "in like manner" be used interchangeably, or do each of these phrases have a special meaning? (or perhaps one is incorrect)?

I've seen both expressions in the Google dictionary:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Like*** is used here as an adjective, meaning

> similar to, or the same as, something else

With this meaning, you can indeed find both variants (with and without ***a***). However, "**in a like manner**" is not very frequent. "**In like manner**" is more idiomatic, as you can see from this [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+a+like+manner%2Cin+like+manner%2Clikewise%2C+similarly&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20like%20manner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20like%20manner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clikewise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csimilarly%3B%2Cc0). It also shows that "**similarly**" and "**likewise**" are preferred.

"**In a like manner**" is probably used having in mind the structure "in + a + adjective + manner/way":

> I would like to answer ***in a similar way***.

This other phrase, "***in similar fashion***", behaves erm... *in like manner* with the phrase "**in like manner**":

> Factors associated with urban place of birth may behave ***in similar
> fashion***. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/similar-fashion))

and

> Smaller units can also be staggered ***in a similar fashion***, or fanned out in arcs if a curved shape works particularly well in the garden. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/similar-fashion))

Note that the variants without "a" (***in like manner*** and ***in similar fashion***) are more formal and they are **set** phrases. You cannot replace "like" or "similar" with any other adjective ("in different manner/fashion" is incorrect). Whereas in the phrases ***in a like manner*** and ***in a similar fashion***, "like" and "similar" can be replaced by any adjective that would make sense in the context.