# He works in like manner with a beaver

Tags: prepositions, definition, dictionaries

> **LIKE** (prep.) in like manner with: *He works **like** a beaver*.
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/like

Is then *He works **in like manner with** a beaver* grammatical ?

Comment: It may have been grammatical centuries ago, but no-one would say it now.,

Comment: Old-fashioned: in like manner to, maybe. "with" no. But really, why bother when there is ** works like an x**? You might like:  in a manner akin to a beaver.

Comment: @Lambie, I thought "In like manner to" better than 'In like manner with". But a Google Ngram shows the two of comparable and low frequency. See my answer below.

Comment: @Lambie, I was commenting only on their (low) frequency of use. I did not attempt to analyze the structure. That might be interesting on ELU, but since this is not a form that a learner should be encourages to use, I did not attempt an analysis of "with" vs "to" here.,

Comment: @Lambie Then, **The man worked in like manner with his son** only meaning **He worked in like manner together with his son**?

Comment: @Lambie **in (a) like manner**?  **1.** [countable] a way of doing, being done, or happening: _In what  **manner**  were you notified?_ ; **5.** [singular* but used with a singular or plural verb] kind; sort: _What **manner** of man is he? All  **manner**  of things were happening_.  https://www.wordreference.com/definition/manner

Comment: @Lambie https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274356/in-like-manner-vs-in-a-like-manner

Comment: I am going to remove all my comments; in a like manner and in like manner mean the same thing. Is that what you are trying to prove? Fine. What that answer **does not say** is that "in like manner" is more old-fashioned. However, "he works in like manner with a beaver" as such with no antecedent as posted by you in your question is not grammatical in English. It could be used a different way. But, you seem to not be interested so bye-bye.

Comment: The man usually works with chickens but sometimes he works in like manner with a pet beaver. Your examples are very poor, and out of context.

Comment: @Lambie In your last example subtitution by (for?) LIKE wouldn't work

Comment: I know what works in English and what does not work. It is you who doesn't get it. It is  you who does not respond to comments like: for the beaver thing, you need an **antecedent**. These context-less phrases you post most often are nonsensical. And finally, "in like manner together with his son" [buzzer]

Answer (score 2):

"In like manner" was once a fairly common phrase, meaning "in the same way as". As [this google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+like+manner%2Cin+like+manner+with%2Cin+like+manner+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20like%20manner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20like%20manner%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20like%20manner%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20like%20manner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20like%20manner%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20like%20manner%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows, it was somewhat common around 1820 (in the group of texts analyzed by Google) and had dropped to around one percent of its former frequency by 1980. As the same Ngram shows, "in like manner with" has at all times been much less common, usually less than one percent of the uses of "in like manner" added "with", and even in the 1800s that was not a common usage. "In like manner to" has similar (but somewhat higher) low frequency of use in this group of texts.

I would only expect to see "In like manner" in documents dating from before 1900, or fiction set in that era. I have encountered the phrase a few times. Particularly in paper [number 5 of *The Federalist*](https://guides.loc.gov/federalist-papers/text-1-10) by John Jay, where the author writes:

> Should the people of America divide themselves into three or four nations, would not the same thing happen? Would not similar jealousies arise, and be in like manner cherished?

Unless one is trying to write as if it is still 1787, or in the manner of 1787, I would avoid the phrase.

"Like" can still be used to mean "the same way". "He works like a beaver" means "He works in the same way as a beaver" or "He works with the same intensity and diligence as a beaver." and is something of a standard phrase, now a bit old-fashioned.